# Can we build a model with different input vector size in training and testing data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, logistic-regression

I build logistic regression model using keras. The shape of my input training vector is 10. `[var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,var8,var9,and var10]`
It is a binary classification, so the target label y is 0 or 1.

Once, I trian the model, I want to do predictions with the input vector of size 6? So, there is a difference between the vector size of training and testing or prediction data.

Is this possible ? Any machine leraning algorithm support such functionalitiy?

The code is as follows:

```
classifier.add(Dense(units = 50, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 5))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))


# compile ANN
classifier.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fitting the data
hisroy =classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 5, epochs = 100)
```

Comment: Why is there different size of vector in train and test?

Comment: because this is the only vectors that i could have in testing data

Comment: Yes but what Are the column differences? Did you generate some features? You should have the same number of columns in both train and test set. I am not aware of any method that could transfer the knowledge from model trained on 10 columns to model for prediction with 6 columns...

Comment: I think the most correct way to handle this is to retrain the model using only the 6 features that are always available. If you're planning to use this model on 6-features data, it is pointless to use the remaining 4 to train the model.

Answer (score 2):

If you are performing predictions using six inputs, but training using ten, then your model will most likely not be as efficient as possible. You essentially are going to have 'dead' correlations because your inputs won't exist - and therefor can't aid well in correlating for the correct output when using new data. By training using those ten inputs, you are also decreasing the possible reliance/correlative behavior from the six inputs you are actually using, since your model learned from all ten. You could technically pad your inputs with default values for the four you aren't using, but once again, I don't see any benefit from training with ten, but predicting with six.